# Delete prestashop order programmatically

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I am developing a payment module for prestashop. The issue is that I have to pass transaction reference to the payment provider, and transaction reference is only generated by prestashop when the order has been validated. Is it possible to programmatically revert an order if for example, the transaction fails, in cases of insufficient funds, or a possible error?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

For edit :

```
$order = New Order($id_order);
$order->current_state = XX; //Id order state
$order->update();
```

For delete :

```
$order = New Order($id_order);
$order->delete();
```

Regards